# appium use and make gesture error alert showing

Tags: appium

Unable to perform W3C actions. Check the logcat output for possible error reports and make sure your input actions chain is valid.

using appium how to wait or watch rendering page

Comment: You can add ExpectedConditions to wait until a provided element is visible or clickable on the page while rendering on the UI.